# Why is this hotswap leaving my application in a bad state?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm

In my application I have a `protected final` [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).  I do the following steps

1. Put a debug point on a line where I call [putIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V))
2. Wait for the application to pause at said debug point
3. Make a minor change to my class like add/remove braces from a 1 line if statement.
4. HotSwap with IntelliJ
5. Let the application continue to completion.  (In this process, the ConcurrentHashMap gets cleared.)

The next time I run to the debug point I have a new instance of my class and a new instance of ConcurrentHashMap, but the ConcurrentHashMap is pre-propulated with an incomplete version of the previous ConcurrentHashMap.

Can anyone explains why this happens?  I know I can avoid it by not HotSwapping mid-debug.  But I'm curious why the JVM behaves this way and allows me to do it.

Comment: after you made the change did you remember to re-compile the class?

Comment: That is done as a part of the hotswapping.

Comment: is your concurrent hash map a static variable ? If so then it's because of the way JVM loads classes. When idea is loading your new modified class, it does that with a new class loader and discards your old one. As the new class loader loads the class again, all the class variables are initialized to null or whatever default values they're declared to

Comment: No, my ConcurrentHashMap is only `protected final`

Comment: can you post the class that you're changing and the code where you're initializing this map ?